# After moving my site from a dev subdomain, to root, all my custom meta data is gone

Tags: custom-field, database, migration, wpalchemy

I just movde my site from a dev subdomain, to the root.  I have extensive amounts of data saved in custom meta fields which I created with the [WpAlchemy class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/).  All of this data is not appearing in the site (back or front end), although it appears to be in the database.

This happened right after attempting to use the search replace plugin to change any lingering urls.  This attempt ended in `Fatal error: Out of memory`.  I noticed everything was gone, so I swapped out the db for my backup (after doing a manual search-replace for my subdomain).  This produced the same result.

I think I've read somewhere that data serialization (am I getting this right?) can mess up this kind of thing.  Is that whats happening to me here?

What steps should I take to get the site up and running ASAP.  Currently it is live, and terribly broken :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there done that. Try this:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
Its a search and replace tool that you put in your WordPress root and just run it from mydomain.dev/searchreplacedb2.php

It fixes the serialization problem when you want to change the url:s to the live one.

Comment: hmmm... I'm always reluctant to download plugins NOT from the official WP repo...

Comment: its not a WordPress specific plugin, its a MySQL search and replace plugin.

Comment: ah yes, just reading up on that now.. thanks.  Actually, I think I used this a couple years ago when first getting into WP

Comment: It should fix the lost data problem, tell me if it does.

Comment: Glad it worked for you too.